# Processing historic aerial imagery mosaics

Tags: remote-sensing, open-source-gis, aerial-photography, historical-imagery

I'd like to process multiple sets of old (>1938) aerial imagery that are scanned, but whether merged nor georeferenced. While I had good results with QGIS to align single photos, using passpoints, this doesn't scale for all the tiles and lacks preprocessing steps:

- remove film-frame
- align all photos to each other
- choose / combine overlapping areas
- composite and color adjustments
- georeference using passpoints + global coordinates

Is there any free / open source toolchain, that can deal with all that?

A user-interface as huginn would be brilliant, but CLI + tutorial could do the job.
My approach would be to use GIMP to create a single image (incl. preprocessing), align it using QGIS and create the final GeoTIFF. 
While the results are only for visual compare and will be embedded within an WMS, I don't need the highest accuracy and would preffer an solution that I can use with my limited knowledge in raster processing. Rectifieng the result is not required.

Unfortunately I don't own the calibration-infos for the cameras, so tools as [MicMac](http://micmac.ensg.eu) doesn't seem to work. The [Orfeo toolbox](https://www.orfeo-toolbox.org/) seems to be focused on detecting passpoints and perform the feature analysis :-/

Answer (score 1):

To make it short, I didn't found an proper open source solution. Some overview:

- [GRASS GIS](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/i.ortho.photo.html) - has all support, but different docs are confusing and tool is to complex
- [orfeo Toolbox](https://www.orfeo-toolbox.org/CookBook/recipes/optpreproc.html) - designed for working with camera sensors, doesn't seem to work, if calibration is unknown
- [OSSIM](https://trac.osgeo.org/ossim/wiki) - no current binary release, old ones doesn't seem to work
- [Mic mac](http://micmac.ensg.eu/index.php/Historical_Orthoimage) - needs calibration data, writing config files by hand, seems to be unusable to me

I was glad and got support by an university collegues who has licensed an commercial application that worked pretty well.

Answer (score -1):

Some updates: I used WebODM by OpenAerialMap, which worked fine. Only defining GroundControllPoints was not that straigtht forward and took some work. Results are pretty, without further adjustments